# SIP Server That Plays Audio Only?

Tags: linux, sip

**I need a SIP server**, hopefully simpler, more efficient and more secure than Asterisk or other full-featured PBX, to just terminate SIP calls and play audio, based on the incoming number.  This would be in a linux environment.

I'm concerned about long-term support, and much-reduced attack surface.  I'm a programmer but a no0b in the SIP world.  I want to avoid the tons of security hassles of a full-featured PBX, let alone the crazy big bills after a hacker gets into it.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally I would build one with pjsip. Assuming you do not need built in registration server all calls would be handled by so called local account. You can use command-line pjsua with auto-answer and auto-play options for initial tests and then add some logic for audio wave selection and perhaps audio player allocation/deallocation (audio players could be active all the time and shared by multiple calls for efficiency if they e.g. contain something like background music).

For security disable not needed parts (TCP, TLS transports, not needed codecs?) and use port other than 5060. In my application I'm also using kind of application-level firewall that blocks requests from hosts that generate suspicious traffic (registrations, malformed SIP requests).

Comment: Its looking very promising!  I will be using the Python binding, as described [here](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Python_SIP_Tutorial).  More after I get some results!

Comment: Why not use plain C/C++? For me python would be unnecessary dependency and you would have compile C code anyway as there is no official/unofficial pjsua or pjsip binaries available (not that I know of).